# Azure AD service principals and assigned groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, openid-connect

I have an Azure AD Enterprise Application configured as a confidential client. The service principal of this application is added to an Azure AD Group and that group is assigned to the application.

I expect to be able to use this manifest configuration to get the group name in the access token using the `client_credentials` grant:

```
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "groups",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": [
                    "cloud_displayname"
                ]
            }
        ],
```

If I set `groupMembershipClaims` to `ApplicationGroup` then I get no `groups` claim in the token at all. If I set it to `All` or `SecurityGroup` then I get the groups claim containing the group OID.

So it appears that `ApplicationGroup`, which is a requirement for using `cloud_displayname`, only works for regular users with the authorization code flow and not for service principals using the `client_credentials` grant. Is this correct because I cannot find anything in online docs about this limitation.

Comment: @Rukmini Not true since `cloud_displayname` became an option (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes)). As long as you set `groupMembershipClaims` to `ApplicationGroup` then it works just fine _for users_ using the authentication code flow.

Answer (score 1):

I created an **Azure Enterprise Application and added group claim** like below:

[image]

And the **Azure AD Application manifest** looks like:

[image]

Now, I generated tokens using **Authorization Code flow** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default 
code:code
redirect_uri:RedirectUrl
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, **I got the group display name** like below:

[image]

Now, I tried to generate the token via **Client Credential Flow**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, I dint not get any group claim:

[image]

Now, I set the **Group Claim as All**:

[image]

I got the **Group IDs** when decoded the token:

[image]

Yes, I agree with you setting `groupMembershipClaims` to `ApplicationGroup`  works with user interaction flow such as authentication code flow.

- `ApplicationGroup` value is used when the user is authenticated, and their group membership is evaluated.
- There is no actual user context involved in the authentication process when the client credentials grant is used; instead, the application's credentials (service principal) are used directly. As a result, the `ApplicationGroup` value has no impact and the access token's "groups" claim is empty.
- As a workaround, you can call Microsoft Graph API to know the details of the group using its OID:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID
```

[image]